# ¿como redireccionar al login siempre que no este autenticado? laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

Quiero que mi aplicacion pase por una verificacion de autentificacion, pero no logro hacerlo.

En el archivo **routes.php**:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@index');
    Route::resource('login', 'Auth\LoginController');
    Route::resource('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::resource('prueba', 'PruebaController');
    Route::resource('tablero', 'TableroController');
    Route::post('tablero/menu','TableroController@menu');
});
```

En el archivo **app/Http/Kernel.php**:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

En el archivo **app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php**:

```
namespace Illuminate\Auth\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The authentication factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string[]  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        // si la persona no inició sesión, entonces ....
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                // si la persona no inició sesión y no es una solicitud ajax
                // enviar al formulario de ingreso
                return redirect()->guest('entrar');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is logged in to any of the given guards.
     *
     * @param  array  $guards
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    protected function authenticate(array $guards)
    {
        if (empty($guards)) {
            return $this->auth->authenticate();
        }

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
                return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
            }
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', $guards);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes `$guard`, en lugar de `$guards` que es lo que esta recibiendo la función, en  app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

Comment: colocalo en la respuesta como lo manejas tu, por favor.

Comment: Básicamente siguiendo la documentación, y funciona correctamente, solo que dicha documentación ocupa `Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente esa redirección se encuentra sobre el fichero app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

donde

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

es quien redirecciona si no estas autenticado, para agregar a algun controlador, puedes hacer lo siguiente, en el methodo __construct()

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

dicho midleware se encuentra en el fichero app/HTTP/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

Comment: Ok, ya revise pero esta tal cual y no redirecciona.

Comment: revisa lo que añadi a la respuesta, si estas siguiendo el manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication, debe de funcionar

Comment: y los tengo exactamente iguales :-/

Comment: Intenta cerrar session en caso de estar logueado y acceder a la ruta que esta bajo el midleware.

Comment: También lo he intentado e igual entra a cualquier url.

Comment: listo hermano, chequee bien lo posteaste, tenia un error en el middleware. Gracias.

Comment: Estaba justamente pensando que no habias declarado tus ServiceProvider.